# Adding Custom Module in CMS Page

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, layout, cms

I have a custom module. I need to add it in home page of my site. I have added block in the content section of my home page. But it didn't display anything. I have also tried the layout part of home page and the result is as in the previous case. These are my codes

**app/code/local/Karaokeshop/Banner/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Karaokeshop_Banner>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Karaokeshop_Banner>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <banner>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Karaokeshop_Banner</module>
                <frontName>banner</frontName>
            </args>
        </banner>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <banner>
                <file>banner.xml</file>
            </banner>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <banner>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Karaokeshop_Banner</module>
                <frontName>banner</frontName>
            </args>
        </banner>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <menu>
       <!-- <banner module="banner">-->
       <cms>
            <title>CMS</title>
            <sort_order>71</sort_order>
            <children>
                <items module="banner">
                    <title>Manage Banner</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>banner/adminhtml_banner</action>
                </items>
            </children>
        </cms>
        <!--</banner>-->
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <Karaokeshop_Banner>
                        <title>Banner Module</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    </Karaokeshop_Banner>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <banner>
                <file>banner.xml</file>
            </banner>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>

<global>
    <models>
        <banner>
            <class>Karaokeshop_Banner_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>banner_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </banner>
        <banner_mysql4>
            <class>Karaokeshop_Banner_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <banner>
                    <table>banner</table>
                </banner>
            </entities>
        </banner_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <banner_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Karaokeshop_Banner</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </banner_setup>
        <banner_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </banner_write>
        <banner_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </banner_read>
    </resources>
    <blocks>
        <banner>
            <class>Karaokeshop_Banner_Block</class>
        </banner>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <banner>
            <class>Karaokeshop_Banner_Helper</class>
        </banner>
    </helpers>
</global>
</config>
```

This is the code I have tried in the content section of home CMS page

```
{{block type="banner/banner" name="home_banner" template="banner/homenewpro.phtml"}}
```

This is the code I have tried in the layout part(within **content** section) of home CMS page.

```
<block type="banner/banner" name="home_banner" template="banner/banner.phtml" />
```

What is the problem with this code? What I have made wrong with  these codes? Help me guys.... Thanks in advance..

Comment: Check the banner.xml file in your template folder

Comment: @KeyulShah   i have tried this code `<layout version="0.1.0">
    <banner_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="banner/banner" name="home_banner">
            </block>
        </reference>
    </banner_index_index>
</layout>`    when i look into the page, the page layout become 1column. however content block is not displaying. my phtml file echo 'test' in it.

Comment: i have also tried this  `<block type="banner/banner" name="home_banner" template="banner/banner.phtml"/>` and this `<block type="banner/banner" name="home_banner" />`. still not displaying the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure the file `Karaokeshop/Banner/Block/Banner.php` exists and contains this class.

```
class Karaokeshop_Banner_Block_Banner extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{
   //class methods here
}
```

also make sure the template `banner/homenewpro.phtml` exists in `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template`.
Just to make sure, you can place it in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template`.

I hope you also created the declaration file `app/etc/modules/Karaokeshop_Banner.xml` with this content.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Karaokeshop_Banner>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Core />
            </depends>
        </Karaokeshop_Banner>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Clear the cache, disable the compilation and give it an other try.

You can also enable the logging from `System->Configuration->Developer` and check `var/log` for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Is your template file including only `<?php echo "test"?>`....? If so then try adding some HTML tags in it like "div". As you see in other magento template files, A phtml file is a combo of both HTML and PHP. So edit your phtml file accordingly and give it a try.